# Capturing and displaying Live camera feed from a web cam using Java

Tags: java, webcam

I'm need of some help - me, being the java novice I am, have taken upon myself the task of building a type of simplified PhotoBooth application in Java (Java 7, for that matter) as a learning exercise.
Unfourtanely, the rare resources I do find on the subject are either poorly documented or seriously outdated (and doesn't work anymore - I'm trying them in both Windows and Linux).

Currently, the only solution I came across is the FMJ project, but his documentation is lacking and I've been having problems starting the most basic app provided with the source files - `FmjStudio`.

I'm looking for any tutorial, guide or resources (doesn't have to be related to FMJ) that will help a novice like me diving into the subject.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's also [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) that hooks into a few APIs, including OpenCV, to provide camera capture.